# Exporting chart from Excel to Powerpoint using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

So after a bit of digging I got some help to find a code to export a chart from Excel to Powerpoint, problem is it is only selecting an object.

```
Sub ertert()
    With New PowerPoint.Application
        With .Presentations.Add
            With .Slides.Add(1, 12)
                ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).CopyPicture xlPrinter, xlPicture
                .Shapes.Paste
                .Shapes(1).Select
                .Application.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignMiddles, True
                .Application.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignCenters, True
            End With
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

the object it's selecting is a chart/vlookup image result inside of a larger chart (the object itself is named) so basically it's only getting a small part of the item itself.

Question is where I went wrong in having it only select an item? Also I would like to know how to modify this code to add to an existing Powerpoint (assuming the existing one is already open).

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to do?

If you are just looking to display a chart that updates based on the content of your excel workbook you can simply copy the chart across and it creates a link between the two. When both your presentation and workbook are open it will update the chart automatically with no need for VBA.

Comment: Hi,

No, the chart in excel will update based on variables and user input. So a certain value will change the chart configuration and output, and thumbnails associated. 

What I am trying to do is take that entire chart (and anything inside it) and export as a .png/.jpeg etc. into a PowerPoint slide. I've been looking at other scripts and I seemed to get error messages I can't diagnose, but with this one it got part of the chart, only an element, but not the whole thing. 

Junker